# Using C *.so library in c++ project(Ubuntu)Using C *.so library in c project(ubuntu)

Tags: c++, c

I have a dynamic library `lib_funcs.so`, written in C. When I link it to a C project (by Code::Blocks) everything is OK, but when I link it to a C++ project and use functions from this library Code::Blocks gives error: `undefined reference to 'functions name'`.

Comment: Why are you re-posting the **exact same question!?**

Comment: because you didn't give me the answer

Comment: **Wat?** [What do you think this is?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179797/ubuntuusing-c-so-library-in-c-project#comment24877125_17179797) [And this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179797/ubuntuusing-c-so-library-in-c-project#comment24877138_17179797) [And this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179797/ubuntuusing-c-so-library-in-c-project#comment24877182_17179797)

Answer (score 4):

When you include the header that declares the functions, wrap that inclusion in an `extern "C"` block.

```
extern "C" {
#include "funcs.h"
}
```

C++ uses name mangling to support function overloading (in which it renames a function to include information about the types of its parameters as well), while C just uses the names that you give the functions. So your C++ code is looking for the functions under their mangled names, not their real names. If you use `extern "C"` around the declarations of the functions, that will cause the C++ compiler to use C style naming conventions, rather than C++.

Comment: i've tried this but it doesn't help

Comment: @PetrLivic I got it wrong the first time, it should be `extern "C"` with quotes. Try that; if it doesn't work, could you paste a short complete example of what doesn't work and the exact error you get into your question?

Comment: you mean 
extern "C" void ....;
extern "C" void 2...;

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the prototypes as `extern "C" { prototypes }` to prevent name mangling.

Comment: where i need to define prototypes?

Comment: In your header file.  You can add a statement in the header file as `#ifdef __cplusplus extern C { #endif` towards the beginning before any prototypes are defined and add another one as `#ifdef __cplusplus } #endif` towards the end.